# python subprocess captured output differs from original output in terminal

Tags: python, string, terminal, subprocess, output

I'm on Windows and I want to capture an output from a subprocess in order to get things from it via regex.
The problem I'm facing - whenever I capture the output it differs from the original terminal output the command generates.

When I hit `cci org list` in the terminal, I'm getting the following output:

```
                      Scratch Orgs

  Default   Name      Days   Expired   Config    Domain
 ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────
            beta      1                beta
            dev       7                dev
            feature   1                feature
            qa        7                qa
            release   1                release

            Connected Orgs

  Default   Name   Username   Expires
 ─────────────────────────────────────
```

Now when I use the following code to do the exact same in a python script:

```
orgListProcess = subprocess.run(
        ['cci', 'org', 'list'], capture_output=True, text=True)

print(orgListProcess.stdout)
```

it creates this output:

```
                      Scratch Orgs
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Default | Name    | Days | Expired | Config  | Domain |
|---------+---------+------+---------+---------+--------|
|         | beta    | 1    |         | beta    |        |
|         | dev     | 7    |         | dev     |        |
|         | feature | 1    |         | feature |        |
|         | qa      | 7    |         | qa      |        |
|         | release | 1    |         | release |        |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
            Connected Orgs
+-------------------------------------+
| Default | Name | Username | Expires |
|---------+------+----------+---------|
+-------------------------------------+
```

How can this happen? As far as I know, this doesn't occur on mac. 
My problem is, that if the names are longer, in the bottom version it starts to make linebreaks instead of just concatenating to the existing name , which makes it incredible hard to work with regex.

Comment: What's the output when you pipe your `cci org list` command into `type`... Perhaps it formats things differently depending on whether it's connected to the screen or to a different pipe?

Comment: That would make sense, how'd I do that? I'm not that familiar with that kind of stuff.

Comment: You can use the pipe `|` character. For example `foo | bar` will make the output of `foo` be the input of `bar`. On Windows, the `type` command just prints out whatever you give it as input (or any files you give it), so you can use `cci org list | type` to make `cci` think that its output isn't going to the terminal (even though it is, just via `type`).

Comment: gives me the following output several times: 
`Get-Content: The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.`

Comment: Oh of course Windows is like that :( Sorry, I don't think I can help any more than that